# NameError: name 'mail' is not defined

Tags: python, gmail, imap, python-3.7

i am very new to programming, i am supposed to count the number of unread eamails in my inbos usiong python. i am getting a name error saying that "mail" is not defined. i am not sure about the logic either. Here is the code:

```html
import imaplib

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
import datetime
import email
import getpass


def readmail():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
    mypassword = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
address = '@mail.com'
mail.login(address, mypassword)
now = datetime.date.today()
mail.select("inbox")
print("Checking for new e-mails for ", address, ".")
typ, messageIDs = mail.search(now, "UNSEEN")
messageIDsString = str(messageIDs[0], encoding='utf8')
listOfSplitStrings = messageIDsString.split(" ")
print (len(listOfSplitStrings))
```

Comment: As a note: reading email is a terrible place to start to learn programming.  IMAP and Email have 30+ years of cruft and garbage to learn before you can use it effectively, and are much more complex then they look on the service.

Comment: @Shruthi, could you please tell us if the answer provided solved your issue? If it did, you should mark it as accepted otherwise it will still show up in the unanswered questions queue. You ask, somebody responds - that's how the forum works

Comment: `'@mail.com'`cannot possibly be a valid email address or account name.

Answer (score 0):

Fix code indentation

```
import imaplib
import datetime
import email
import getpass

def readmail():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
    mypassword = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    address = '@mail.com'
    mail.login(address, mypassword)
    now = datetime.date.today()
    mail.select("inbox")
    print("Checking for new e-mails for ", address, ".")
    typ, messageIDs = mail.search(now, "UNSEEN")
    messageIDsString = str(messageIDs[0], encoding='utf8')
    listOfSplitStrings = messageIDsString.split(" ")
    print (len(listOfSplitStrings))

if __name__=="__main__":
    readmail()
```

Comment: You might want to add a \_\_main__ guard that class this function; since this won't do anything, as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: You lost the `import imaplib`, no doubt because the OP's code had some formatting issues around that.

Comment: @tripleee thank you, did that, yes the OP's code had formatting issue. Now the answer should be good to go